# Validation error when creating record where model has 1:n relationship with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm getting a form validation error when I'm trying to create a record where the request data is coming from a form.

The model is as below.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace NVFlexo.Models;

[Index(nameof(CategoryName), IsUnique = true)]
public class ItemCategory
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    
    public List<Item> Items { get; }
}
```

Post request method in the controller is as below.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Create(ItemCategory obj)
{
    
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _db.ItemCategories.Add(obj);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    TempData["success"] = "Item Category Created Successfully";
    return View(obj);
}
```

The view is as below.

```
@model ItemCategory

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create New Item Category";
    Layout = "_Layout";
}
<div class="container">
    <form method="post">
        <div class="border p-3 mt-4">
            <div class="row pb-2">
                <h2 class="text-primary">Create Item Category</h2>
                <hr/>
            </div>
            <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label asp-for="CategoryName"></label>
                <input asp-for="CategoryName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="CategoryName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 200px">Create Item Category</button>
            <a asp-controller="ItemCategory" asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-secondary" style="width: 150px;">Back to List</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
@section Scripts
{
    @{
        <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial"/>
    }
}
```

The form validation error I get is

> The Items field is required.

Seems like it is looking for a Items List variable but the form is not sending this as I'm simply trying to create the item category object.

Is there anyway to create the record without setting a DTO and referencing to it by manually mapping for a new "ItemCategory" object?

Comment: EF Core navigations should probably be nullable so you don't have to include them in all queries. But you shouldn't be binding your data model directly. That's what view models are for.

Comment: You can try to add `?` like :  `public List<Item>? Items { get; set;}`

Comment: Actually EF Core **collection** navigations should **never** be nullable, and should be initialized with empty list (or whatever collection type is used for storage).

Comment: Could you not just create a `CreateItemCategoryModel` which only contains the `CategoryName` property? That's typically what's done in situations like this. If you allow upserting you can include the `Id` property as well of course.